# Bulk data entry with a clipboard array

Tags: text, copy-paste, data-entry

I'm trying to find a script, app, or even a language that would allow me to simplify text entry. I want to take a list of values that I need to enter (delimited by line breaks, pipes, anything), bulk load them into an array (similar to individual items in Office's Clipboard feature), and use a single key/combination to paste the items sequentially wherever I have my cursor.

A simple example would be if I took the following string, "1|2|3|4|5", loaded it into the script, place my cursor where I want to paste, hit a key to paste the first item, move my cursor, hit a key to paste the second item, etc.

Comment: While this could very well be a programming question, I suspect you'll have better luck on SuperUser.

Comment: Good point, I want the functionality more than the code to build it. Thanks Adrian.